# Один сайт - разное меню

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый вечер!

Есть страница. Верстка адаптивная.
Для десктопов и планшетов меню одного вида (линейное), для мобильных устройств - другого (скрытое).

Вот js-код для мобильных:

```
$('.btn-menu, .menu a').click(function() {
    var btn = $('.btn-menu');
    var menu = $('.menu');

    if ( $(window).width() <= 712 ) { 
        if ( menu.css('display') == 'none' ) {
            menu.show();
            btn.removeClass('arrow-open').addClass('arrow-close');
        } else {
            menu.hide();
            btn.removeClass('arrow-close').addClass('arrow-open');
        }
    }
    return false
});
```

Получается следующая ерунда ...: Мобильных устройств огромное количество с самыми разнообразными диагоналями. **Что можно прописать вместо размеров окна, чтобы данный код работал только на смартфонах?**

Дело в том, что при уменьшении окна на десктопных браузерах, когда нажимаем на элемент меню - **.menu a**, меню скрывается, чего, как Вы понимаете происходить не должно.

**В общем, как решить данную задачу, может кто сталкивался?**

Спасибо.

**UPD:** такая же история со слайдером, нужно, чтобы он работал только на планшетах и десктопах, но не на мобильных ...

Comment: Может в версии браузера что то есть?

Comment: И надо это только средствами веба или есть доступ и к серверной части?

Comment: К серверу доступа нет, нужно все сделать на клиенте.

Comment: @Astor, адаптивная верстка, в моем понимании, это верстка, которая позволяет удобно просматривать страницу, иметь удобным доступ к навигации, элеметам формы и прочему, при **любом размере просматриваемой области**. И при чем тут диагонали, планшеты и мобильные? До определенного размера по ширине - удобно распологать меню в раскрытом виде, а меньше этого размера, например, как выпадающее.

Comment: @Deonis, возможно я неправильно выразился. Просто на основе одной структуры (html - каркаса), сделаны десктопная и мобильная версия. В десктопной, как я уже говорил, меню линейное, а в мобильной выпадающее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение данной задачи, оказалось крайне простым, а именно:**

*в таблицу стилей для мобильных устройств прописываем класс*

```
.menu-show { display: block; }
```

*и с помощью JS добавляем его, либо убираем, в зависимости от логики:*

```
$('.btn-menu, .menu a').click(function() {
    var btn = $('.btn-menu');
    var menu = $('.menu');

    if ( $(window).width() <= 712 ) { 
        if ( menu.css('display') == 'none' ) {
            menu.addClass('menu-show');
            btn.removeClass('arrow-open').addClass('arrow-close');
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('menu-show');
            btn.removeClass('arrow-close').addClass('arrow-open');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Оно то так, но почему бы всё это не сделать в css с помощью [@media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media)?   ` .menu-show {   display: block;    }    @media (max-width: 712px) {        .menu-show {            display: none;        }    } `

Comment: @Deonis, в конечном счете, к этому и пришел. 

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Думаю ссылка Вам поможет: [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://javascript.ru/forum/mobile/25801-detect-mobile-browsers-2.html)
Или эта: [Поддержка JavaScript на мобильных устройствах](http://www.xiper.net/learn/bonus-books/programming-the-mobile-web/javascript-mobile/javascript-mobile-compatibility.html)